# Product of a Schubert polynomial and a double Schubert polynomial

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, algebraic-combinatorics, positivity, schubert-calculus

Let $S_u(x)$ be a Schubert polynomial and let $S_v(x;y)$ be a double Schubert polynomial. Then their product can be expressed in terms of the double Schubert polynomials as
$$S_u(x)S_v(x;y)=\sum_w{c_{uv}^w(y)S_w(x;y)}$$
where the $c_{uv}^w(y)$ are polynomials in the $y$ variables.

If $u,v$ are Grassmannian permutations for the same parabolic subgroup, then the Molev–Sagan rule for factorial Schur functions implies that $c_{uv}^w(y)$ has nonnegative integer coefficients. Is it known whether $c_{uv}^w(y)$ has nonnegative coefficients for general permutations?

As mentioned in the [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212762/product-of-a-schubert-polynomial-and-a-double-schubert-polynomial#comment527414_212762) below, I've tested this up to $n=6$. Since proving positivity of these coefficients subsumes proving positivity of the structure constants in ordinary cohomology of flag varieties, any proof with current tools would likely be geometric. I think the key would be the double/triple Schubert calculus mentioned in Knutson and Tao's paper "[Puzzles and (equivariant) cohomology of Grassmannians](https://doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-03-11922-5)," so I'm basically wondering if anyone has studied those concepts enough to have a geometric proof of positivity for the complete flag variety.

This question is almost 9 years old, but in 2015 I [mentioned](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212762/product-of-a-schubert-polynomial-and-a-double-schubert-polynomial#comment532724_212762) I had a Pieri formula for this. It was super hard to prove, but it is now to appear in JPAA, along with a separated descents formula: [A Molev–Sagan type formula for double Schubert polynomials](https://arxiv.org/abs/2401.11060).

I have more unpublished results in this direction. Still looking for a geometric proof.

Comment: Have you tried some computer experiments on this? Of course, proving this is probably very hard unless there is some representation-theoretical way to do it.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson I've tested it up to $n=6$.

Comment: I believe I have a Pieri formula for this now.

Comment: Though it doesn't explicitly answer the question, you might find the end of this note relevant: https://people.math.osu.edu/anderson.2804/eilenberg/lecture11.pdf

Comment: Also, I think the method from this note might adapt to your situation: http://arxiv.org/abs/0711.0983